# Data binding of states between paper elements

Tags: data-binding, polymer, web-component

Is it possible to bind a state (attribute) of a paper-checkbox [checked|unchecked] dynamically to an attribute like [readonly|disabled] inside a paper-input element? This is my implementation so far:

```
<template repeat="{{item in lphasen}}">
  <div center horizontal layout>
    <paper-checkbox unchecked on-change="{{checkStateChanged}}" id="{{item.index}}"></paper-checkbox>
      <div style="margin-left: 24px;" flex>
        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="container"><paper-input disabled floatingLabel id="{{item.index}}" label="LABEL2" value="{{item.percent}}" style="width: 120px;"></paper-input></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The behavior should be as follow:
When the user uncheck a paper-checkbox, then the paper-input element in the same row should be disabled and/or readonly and vice versa. Is it possible to directly bind multiple elements with double-mustache or do I have to iterate the DOM somehow to manually set the attribute on the paper-input element? If YES, could someone explain how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to bind the checked state of the paper-checkbox.

```
<polymer-element name="check-input">
<template>
    <style>
    #checkbox {
      margin-left: 1em;
    }
    </style>
    <div center horizontal layout>
        <div><paper-input floatingLabel label="{{xlabel}}" value="{{xvalue}}" disabled="{{!xenable}}" type="number" min="15" max="200"></paper-input></div>
        <div><paper-checkbox id="checkbox" label="Enable" checked="{{xenable}}"></paper-checkbox></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('check-input', {
  publish:{xenable:true, xvalue:'',xlabel:''}
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
    <div>
       <check-input xenable="true" xvalue="100" xlabel="Weight.1"></check-input>
       <check-input xenable="false" xvalue="185" xlabel="Weight.2"></check-input>
   </div>
```

jsbin demo http://jsbin.com/boxow/

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach would be to refactor the code to create a Polymer element responsible for one item.  That way, all of the item specific behaviour is encapsulated in one place.

Once that is done, there are a couple ways of doing this.

The easiest would be to simply create an on-tap event for the check box that toggles the value of a property and sets the disabled attribute accordingly.

```
<paper-checkbox unchecked on-tap="{{checkChanged}}"></paper-checkbox>
//Other markup for item name display
<paper-input disabled floatingLabel id="contextRelevantName" style="width:120 px;"></paper-input>
```

One of the benefits of putting this into it's own polymer element is that you don't have to worry about unique id's anymore.  The control id's are obfuscated by the shadowDOM.

For the scripting, you would do something like this:

```
publish: {
  disabled: {
    value: true,
    reflect: false
  }
}

checkChanged: function() {
  this.$.disabled= !this.$.disabled;
  this.$.contextRelevantName.disabled = this.$.disabled;
}
```

I haven't tested this, so there might be some tweaks to syntax and what have you, but this should get you most of the way there.

**Edit**

Based on the example code provided in your comment below, I've modified your code to get it working.  The key is to make 1 element that contains an either row, not multiple elements that contain only parts of the whole.  so, the code below has been stripped down a little bit to only include the check box and the input it is supposed to disable.  You can easily add more to the element for other parts of your item displayed.

```
<polymer-element name="aw-leistungsphase" layout vertical attributes="label checked     defVal contractedVal">
<template>
<div center horizontal layout>
    <div>
    <paper-checkbox checked on-tap="{{checkChanged}}" id="checkbox" label="{{label}}"></paper-checkbox>
    </div>

      <div class="container"><paper-input floatingLabel id="contractedInput" label="Enter Value" value="" style="width: 120px;"></paper-input></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer('aw-leistungsphase', {

  publish: {
    /**
     * The label for this input. It normally appears as grey text inside
     * the text input and disappears once the user enters text.
     *
     * @attribute label
     * @type string
     * @default ''
     */
    label: '',
    defVal : 0,
    contractedVal : 0
  },

  ready: function() {
    // Binding the project to the data-fields
    this.prj = au.app.prj;
    // i18n mappings
    this.i18ndefLPHLabel = au.xlate.xlate("hb.defLPHLabel");
    this.i18ncontractedLPHLabel = au.xlate.xlate("hb.contractedLPHLabel");
  },

  observe : {
    'contractedVal' : 'changedLPH'
  },

  changedLPH: function(oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      //this.prj.hb.honlbl = newVal;
      console.log("Geänderter Wert: " + newVal);
    }
  },
  checkChanged: function(e, detail, sender) {

    console.log(sender.label + " " + sender.checked);
    if (!this.$.checkbox.checked) {
      this.$.contractedInput.disabled = 'disabled';
    }
    else {
      this.$.contractedInput.disabled = '';
    }

    console.log("Input field disabled: " + this.$.contractedInput.disabled);
  }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Hi Casses. I did not see the whole picture here. As you pointed out, I have separated the group of paper-checkbox and paper-input into own elements. Inside the element with the paper-checkbox I have the script to handle check/uncheck state of the checkbox `checkChanged`. I've put the `publish` part inside my own paper-input element but the change of the checkbox state won't be reflected there and I can't disable the paper-input element. I would like to share my implementation with you but I don't now how? Is there a prefered way for sharing code?

Comment: check out [jsfiddle.net](http://jsFiddle.net).  Put your code there, and post a link to it in your question.  I'll take a look at it then.

Comment: The first part of my custom paper-checkbox element which should toggle my custom paper-input element is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dominikk0711/uevbxxna/ My custom paper-input element is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dominikk0711/tomkayLu/

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a working sample of your code.

Comment: Hi Casses. This is "somehow" working but disabled paper-input elements do have a dashed underline which will not appear, when the disabled attribute is set through the code. Instead when I break in the code with the debugger and set the attribute `disabled` to the appropriate paper-element tag, then the dashed underline appears. Really strange! BTW. do you know why the disabled attribute of the paper-element is **NOT** a boolean and why do I have to set the string `disabled` instead?